# Passing POST data from Objective-C to PHP

Tags: php, ios, json, post

I'm trying to pass some POST data from Objective-c to PHP but the PHP file doesn't seem to be getting the data.

Here is how I am sending it:

```
- (void) sendJSONData:(NSDictionary *)dictData {

    NSError *error;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kRootWebService];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                             @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                             nil];
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@" URL: %@", request);
    NSLog(@" Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse.allHeaderFields);
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"This is my print out of data to string\n%@",str);

            //deseriealize the return
            id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

            NSDictionary* dictJSON;
            NSArray* arrJSON;

            NSLog(@"%@", dictJSON);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"There was an error connecting with the server, the status code returned was %i", (int)httpResponse.statusCode);

        }

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];


}
```

Here's the log of the URL (the URL is correct) and Body:

```
URL: http://xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx.php }
2017-07-30 15:20:10.602 MirrorBox[89680:5646406]  Body: {"name":"TEST IOS","typemap":"IOS TYPE"}
```

Here's the log of the request headers

```
2017-07-30 15:20:10.751 MirrorBox[89680:5646478] {
    Age = 0;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 34;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 30 Jul 2017 19:20:10 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.22";
}
```

This is the log of the returned data, the error message is my own:

```
This is my print out of data to string
{"key":"could not read POST data"}
```

And here is the PHP file:

```
<?php

    if (!$_POST['IOS_TYPE']) { 
        echo json_encode(array("key" => "could not read POST data"));
    } else { 
        echo json_encode(array("key" => "returned string"));
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass  the POST with key  .. you  should accessing using the same keys

```
 <?php

   if (!$_POST['typemap']) { 
      echo json_encode(array("typemap" => "could not read POST data"));
   } else { 
       echo json_encode(array("typemap" => "returned string"));
   }


?>
```

or better

```
  if (isset($_POST['typemap'])){
     if ($_POST['typemap'] == 'IOS TYPE' ) {
          echo 'IOS TYPE type in typemap POST';
     }
 }
  .....
```

Comment: I should of mentioned I had that earlier and thought maybe I was reading the keys backwards, but I do it as in your answer I still don't hit the $_POST data

Comment: it's an empty array

Comment: this mean that you are not sending values  in POST

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the JSON in the body of the request, try this way :

```
 $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj     = json_decode($content , false);      // decode to stdObj
 $typemap = $obj->typemap;
```

or if you prefer to work with associative arrays :

```
 $ary     = json_decode($content , true);      // decode to array
 $typemap = $ary['typemap'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.

Comment: my pleasure ... and also, dont work PHP blind, work with a good IDE !

Comment: I'm writing an iOS app and just needed to be able to store user settings to a back end. It's been years since I've written any PHP and I am obviously rusty. I am writing that code in Coda so I should look into it more for debugging.